# DAX Creating a New Table from an Old Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table named "Table 1" that looks like this:

```
col_1     col_2
steve     smith
steve     john
linda     jones
johnny    apple
linda     jones
```

I want to create a new table that contains only distinct values of those 2 columns, so final result would be:

```
col_1     col_2
steve     smith
steve     john
linda     jones
johnny    apple
```

I started playing with `SELECTCOLUMNS`, but I don't think I'm doing it right, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Distinct(table) dax to achieve it.
Returns a table by removing duplicate rows from another table or expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Summarize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax) it will pull out distinct values from columns :

```
Table_Output =  Summarize(Table_IN,Col1,Col2,Col3,...,Coln)
```

Or  [Distinct()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/distinct-table-function-dax):

```
Table_Output  = DISTINCT(Table_IN)
```